# Template setting page for Symfony/Twig missing after PhpStorm IDE Error

Tags: php, symfony, twig, phpstorm

I just tried to configure my Twig settings for PhpStorm, to get autocomplete and quick jumping for template files. However it seems like I entered a wrong path which killed the settings page and generated an fatal error.

Here is the PhpStorm stacktrace:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Argument for @NotNull parameter 'path' of fr/adrienbrault/idea/symfony2plugin/templating/path/TwigPath.<init> must not be null
at fr.adrienbrault.idea.symfony2plugin.templating.path.TwigPath.$$$reportNull$$$0(TwigPath.java)
at fr.adrienbrault.idea.symfony2plugin.templating.path.TwigPath.<init>(TwigPath.java)
at fr.adrienbrault.idea.symfony2plugin.templating.util.TwigUtil.getTwigNamespaces(TwigUtil.java:1337)
at fr.adrienbrault.idea.symfony2plugin.templating.util.TwigUtil.getTemplateNamesForFile(TwigUtil.java:1242)
at fr.adrienbrault.idea.symfony2plugin.templating.util.TwigUtil.getTemplatesExtendingFile(TwigUtil.java:2180)
at fr.adrienbrault.idea.symfony2plugin.templating.util.TwigUtil.getTemplatesExtendingFile(TwigUtil.java:2168)
at fr.adrienbrault.idea.symfony2plugin.twig.loader.FileImplementsLazyLoader.getFiles(FileImplementsLazyLoader.java:35)
at fr.adrienbrault.idea.symfony2plugin.twig.utils.TwigBlockUtil.hasBlockImplementations(TwigBlockUtil.java:66)
at fr.adrienbrault.idea.symfony2plugin.templating.TwigLineMarkerProvider.attachBlockImplements(TwigLineMarkerProvider.java:197)
at fr.adrienbrault.idea.symfony2plugin.templating.TwigLineMarkerProvider.collectSlowLineMarkers(TwigLineMarkerProvider.java:80)
at com.intellij.codeInsight.daemon.impl.LineMarkersPass.a(LineMarkersPass.java:197)
at com.intellij.codeInsight.daemon.impl.LineMarkersPass.a(LineMarkersPass.java:96)
at com.intellij.codeInsight.daemon.impl.Divider.divideInsideAndOutsideInOneRoot(Divider.java:80)
at com.intellij.codeInsight.daemon.impl.LineMarkersPass.doCollectInformation(LineMarkersPass.java:91)
at com.intellij.codeHighlighting.TextEditorHighlightingPass.collectInformation(TextEditorHighlightingPass.java:69)
at com.intellij.codeInsight.daemon.impl.PassExecutorService$ScheduledPass.e(PassExecutorService.java:423)
at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.tryRunReadAction(ApplicationImpl.java:1161)
at com.intellij.codeInsight.daemon.impl.PassExecutorService$ScheduledPass.d(PassExecutorService.java:416)
at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.a(CoreProgressManager.java:580)
at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.executeProcessUnderProgress(CoreProgressManager.java:525)
at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl.executeProcessUnderProgress(ProgressManagerImpl.java:85)
at com.intellij.codeInsight.daemon.impl.PassExecutorService$ScheduledPass.a(PassExecutorService.java:415)
at com.intellij.codeInsight.daemon.impl.PassExecutorService$ScheduledPass.b(PassExecutorService.java:391)
at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ReadMostlyRWLock.executeByImpatientReader(ReadMostlyRWLock.java:147)
at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.executeByImpatientReader(ApplicationImpl.java:222)
at com.intellij.codeInsight.daemon.impl.PassExecutorService$ScheduledPass.run(PassExecutorService.java:389)
at com.intellij.concurrency.JobLauncherImpl$VoidForkJoinTask$1.exec(JobLauncherImpl.java:161)
at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:289)
at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:1056)
at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1692)
at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:157)
```

And that's how the settings page looks:

[image: empty settings page]

How can I reset the settings page? I already uninstalled the Symfony plugin (which adds/remove the setting page) which had no effect, I still had the empty page on reinstall.

Comment: What error are you getting with symfony plugin disabled?

Comment: When I disable the symfony plugin I don't get an error - which is because the settings page is only visible because of the symfony plugin. Like I said after reinstalling the settings page is broken again.

Comment: Hm, try to disable ALL custom plugins first. That should help in 99% of cases. Otherwise try to purge your .PhpStorm2018.3 directory, see https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/tuning-the-ide.html#default-dirs

Comment: I have the same issue. I tried to disable ALL custom plugins, but it didn't help. I have non-standard directory structure though - 2 Symfony projecst in "projects/A" and "projects/B" directories.

Comment: @TomášVotruba thanks for commenting, I did not solve the problem in the meantime. Let me know if you do! What I did not try yet is a complete reinstall, I want to avoid that..

Comment: Hi, I think I found a better way: https://github.com/Haehnchen/idea-php-symfony2-plugin/issues/1105#issuecomment-448664968

Comment: Not sure if this help, but I removed my `.idea` on my project and it worked for me:

I found my solution here:
https://github.com/Haehnchen/idea-php-symfony2-plugin/issues/1222

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This solution worked for me:

- Open the project .idea directory in your OS file explorer
- Locate the symfony2.xml file
- Rename the file to something like symfony2_bkup.xml
- Re-install the plugin
- Restart PHPStorm
- Allow the prompt to enable with auto configuration
- Go to Settings > Languages & Frameworks > PHP > Symfony > Twig / Template
- Should now work OK.
- If you have previous settings, copy them from the backup xml file to the new one thats been generated.

**UPDATE**

After further debugging, it turns out if you have something like this in your xml file:

```
<option name="twigNamespaces">
  <list>
    <twig_namespace custom="true" namespace="MyCompany" namespaceType="ADD_PATH" />
  </list>
</option>
```

Then you need to add the path attribute like so:

```
<option name="twigNamespaces">
  <list>
    <twig_namespace custom="true" namespace="MyCompany" namespaceType="ADD_PATH" path="path/to/custom/views" />
  </list>
</option>
```

Once you save the xml file changes, be sure to restart PHPStorm!